# sql table name, item or items

Tags: sql, postgresql, naming, conventions

I name my tables according to what the row describes. So if it describes one comment in one row, I name it "comment".

I have a table with id, created_at, updated_at, name, description, quantity, sample. I am unsure what to name it due to "quantity". I think it can be seen in two ways.

1. The table describes one specific kind of item. There are x number of this one kind of item. As such the table should be named "item". Similar to fish vs fishes.
2. The table describes many items in each row due to quantity. As such it should be named "items". The caveat is that there can be 0 or 1 of the item.

I've also entertained the idea that quantity may be describing a subtly different entity and belongs in a separate table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, I think this is a style thing, but I think you should be consistent across your tables rather than trying to come up with a different concept table by table.

Personally I prefer singular because of the inconsistencies of pluralizing words, but a lot of people prefer plural because the table seems to be a collection of things.

In your example, though, I'm not sure why the presence of "quantity" as one of your columns would factor in. A table called "animal" could have a "number_of_legs" column, but I don't think that would change the way you think about the overall table of animals.

Answer (score 1):

Item.

Each row contains a kind of item. A property of the item is the quantity.  If each specific item had a separate row, and included a column such as SerialNumber, then Items would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Each row is not exactly describing an item, but an item bundle, right? Either way, don't overthink it.

From your question I would use 'item' because it's gonna be more similar to your other tables.